# Gat OAuth Token From UIWebView Cache Swift

Tags: swift, oauth, uiwebview, nsurlcache, nshttpcookie

I am presenting a UIWebView in my App, I need to get the OAuth Token that stored on the device Cache after client login but i don't know how.

i try so search the cookie, but didn't get the result.

```
for cookie in NSHTTPCookieStorage.sharedHTTPCookieStorage().cookies!{

    var C:NSHTTPCookie = cookie as NSHTTPCookie

    println("\(cookie.name)\n")
}
```

thanks for the help.

Comment: Are you saying that you've requested the token from the server and are trying to fetch the token and token secret, or are you saying you've already authenticated and are returning to the webView as second time?

Comment: already authenticated and returning to the webView second time.